# Handling 'no records available' during ConsumerSeekAware seekToTimestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

The requirement is to consume only those records from a topic which have a timestamp greater than or equal to the given timestamp.
Plan to achieve this is to have the corresponding listener container in pause state and resume after seekToTimestamp is performed, to consume the returned records on the next poll.

The issue is when using ConsumerSeekAware seekToTimestamp API, the following exception is thrown when there are no records available in the topic that has a timestamp greater than or equal to the given timestamp.

`IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'java.lang.NullPointerException's; no record information is available`

Can we identify that the offset did not change during seekToTimestamp or that there are no records to be seeked after seekToTimestamp(), so that the necessary operations can be performed on a "no record available" scenario.

NPE stack trace -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$processTimestampSeeks$31(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2048)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processTimestampSeeks(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2048)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processSeeks(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:970)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace; if this NPE is being thrown by the framework, it is a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: Yes, when there are no records to seek on a partition for a given timestamp NPE is thrown, edited the question with stack trace @GaryRussell

Comment: What version are you using? This was fixed over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by writing a custom error handler similar to the default available *SeekToCurrentErrorHandler*.
When there are no records returned by seekToTimestamp method, the exception reaches the custom handler and the required operation after receiving the exception, can be performed here.

Sample ErrorHandler implementation -

```
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerAwareErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor;

public class CustomErrorHandler extends FailedRecordProcessor implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler {

private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorHandler.class);

public CustomErrorHandler() {
    this(null, SeekUtils.DEFAULT_BACK_OFF);
}

protected CustomErrorHandler(BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> recoverer, BackOff backOff) {
    super(recoverer, backOff);
}

@Override
public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
    
 // Handle operations after exception

}}
```

But depending on the requirement, need to make sure that we are not compromising on functionalities that the default SeekToCurrentErrorHandler provides, for my use case the above custom handler implementation is sufficient.